# CAN bus possibilities?

Tags: microcontroller, can, sensor-node

Is it possible to add something, such as a microcontroller, to act as a new node that will integrate into the CAN bus system and be dominant over other nodes or at least speak on the bus to work what you're trying to work other than reverse engineer the whole CAN bus?

Comment: Well you could set the identifier to all zero's so it wins the arbitration BUT this is extremely rude and a very easy way to jam up the bus if you are not careful

Comment: CAN is a peer to peer or broadcast bus so any node can talk to any other node.  As @JonRB 's comment hinted, arbitration for collisions is resolved by identifier, You can implement the protocol on whatever host controller you want. Keep in mind in certain industries, the industry Physical layer spec may override CAN so tranceivers are not as plug and play as most people would hope.

Comment: To address the last sentence: there is **no way** you can add another node to a CAN bus without knowing exactly what messages there are on the bus. It just doesn't make any sense - if you don't know what messages there are, you won't be able to communicate. So yes, you need to reverse-engineer the whole bus if you have no documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course you can use a microcontroller as a node. I had used the CAN bus recently connected to three other microcontrollers (nodes). The biggest advantage of using CAN is that the CAN controller hardware present takes care of data collision and timing and so on which makes programming a CAN oriented system much easier.

If you had to work a bus topology using UART then it would have been much more difficult, but CAN is very convenient. And there is no dominant node on the bus; all nodes in CAN listen to whatever each node is sending, but by setting the acceptance filter value you can filter the contents. Every message has an ID and using the ID we get to know what the content of the data is about. A good basic framework of CAN is provided in the following link which you could check out.
https://www.kvaser.com/about-can/the-can-protocol/

And the priority of the message being sent in the node depends on the identifier value of the message. A smaller identifier corresponds to a higher priority and there are also priority configuration where a particular node can send a message as soon as the current transaction is completed. Since all nodes listen to what you are sending the node that you want to act like a master could be close to a master.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question,

> Is it possible to add something such as a micro controller to act as a new node that will integrate into the can bus system

Yes it is possible, Basically CAN is a broadcast communication and any number of nodes can be added and removed that will never affect the performance of the other nodes in the bus.

> be dominate over other nodes

CAN is not a Master-Slave or Address protocol like SPI to dominate other nodes. It is more of like a message based protocol. Which means your node cannot dominate, but CAN frames can dominate in the bus.

> or at least speak on the bus to work what your trying to work.

Yes, you can transmit frames to the CAN bus, But most of the time, it might go unattended. Because, the acceptance filter configuration of the receiving node might not support the frame ID you're trying to send.

> Other than reverse engineer the whole CAN bus. ?

I think you should reverse engineer the whole CAN bus to the acceptance filter configuration of the intended ECU, making your message more "dominant" than others etc.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up most likely other nodes have acceptance filters which means the data you transmit will be ignored by the other nodes. On the other hand you can indeed receive all the messages with a mask 0x00 (if it is not a higher level protocol like J1939.) and yes you can add microcontrollers as nodes. However, it might be problematic if the address you choose for your microcontroller is same with the address of already existing node. So in order to prevent this, you may want to give your new node low priority.